# explanation of inherited code - sorts an array but I'm not sure how

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update a macro to add some new information to log sheets and a couple other fixes.  I want to understand how this codes sorts an array (why are there 3 variable) so I don't break the macro when I update it.

I understand the array components - but i'm not sure how the columns end up sorted into the array order when the loops are finished.

```
Dim rang As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Temp
Dim nams As Variant
Dim F
Dim Dex As Integer
nams = Array("Assay_type", "Revd_date", "Lab#", "Outside#", "Last,First 
Name", "MRN", "DOB", "Requestor", "CollDate", "Sample_info", 
"Order_Comment", "Signout_comment", "Sample_Comment", "Materials_recvd", 
"Order_status", "DIagnosis.1", "Molec_Summary")
Set rang = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For i = 1 To rang.Columns.Count
    For j = i To rang.Columns.Count
        For F = 0 To UBound(nams)
            If nams(F) = rang(j) Then Dex = F: Exit For
        Next F
        If F < i Then
            Temp = rang.Columns(i).value
            rang(i).Resize(rang.Rows.Count) = rang.Columns(j).value
            rang(j).Resize(rang.Rows.Count) = Temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

I added two new columns to the array and I want to make sure the code will sort them with no problem. I'm just learning to make and update these macros and would like to be careful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  So the sort values come from the position in the array list?    Make an answer so I can mark correct.